# Gap between rows

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

The gap between the grid rows is too big. Adding more photos or setting the `.image` height to 100% fixes it, but then it stretches out the photo.

The gap between `.description` and `#gallery` flex items is too big.

Gallery height of 100% fixes everything but then the gap between the grid rows becomes bigger:

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px 10px 0px;
  height: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(50rem, 1fr));
  column-gap: 10px;
  row-gap: 10px;
  margin: 0px 30px;
  top: 0px;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 0px;
}

.description {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  padding-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p class="description"> text</p>
  <div id="gallery">
    <a href="01.jpg"><img class="image"  src="https://placekitten.com/408/287" alt=""></a>
    <a href="01.jpg"><img class="image"  src="https://placekitten.com/408/287" alt=""></a>
    <a href="01.jpg"><img class="image"  src="https://placekitten.com/408/287" alt=""></a>
    <a href="01.jpg"><img class="image"  src="https://placekitten.com/408/287" alt=""></a>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: For the second part of your question, have you tried changing the default margin of <p>?

Comment: Yes, nothing changed. It has to do with the flexbox but i can't figure it out what

Answer (score 0):

You have too much CSS.

Here is what you can get with less styles:

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

#gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100%, 1fr));
  column-gap: 10px;
  row-gap: 10px;
  margin: 0 30px;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.description {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p class="description"> text</p>
  <div id="gallery">
    <a href="01.jpg"><img class="image" src="https://placekitten.com/408/287" alt=""></a>
    <a href="01.jpg"><img class="image" src="https://placekitten.com/408/287" alt=""></a>
    <a href="01.jpg"><img class="image" src="https://placekitten.com/408/287" alt=""></a>
    <a href="01.jpg"><img class="image" src="https://placekitten.com/408/287" alt=""></a>
  </div>
</main>
```

When it comes to spacing, [everything in CSS is a box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model). Something that helps me is styling every single element with a 1px red outline to see where all the boxes are on the page, which I have set up in this next snippet.
I've also set the sane default for [box sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to border box.
When you set zero on something you don't need a unit. 0px --> 0
Here are some more changes I made:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  /* text-align: center; does nothing */
  /* margin: 0 10px 0; Immediately overridden by the margin below */
  /* height: 100%; does nothing */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center; /* centers your description and gallery within <main> */
  /* flex: 1; child flex property, does nothing here */
  /* overflow-y: auto; This is causing you pain */
  padding: 0 5px;
  /* margin: 0; Overrides margin above, why? There is no margin on <main> by default. */
}

#gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100%, 1fr)); /* 50rem is not responsive */
  column-gap: 10px;
  row-gap: 10px;
  margin: 0 30px;
  /* top: 0px; not positioned, so this does nothing */
  /* align-items: stretch; not needed */
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  /* margin: 0; <img> have no default margin */
}

.description {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  margin: 0; /* remove default margin on <p> */
  /* padding-top: 0; <p> doesn't have default padding */
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p class="description"> text</p>
  <div id="gallery">
    <a href="01.jpg"><img class="image" src="https://placekitten.com/408/287" alt=""></a>
    <a href="01.jpg"><img class="image" src="https://placekitten.com/408/287" alt=""></a>
    <a href="01.jpg"><img class="image" src="https://placekitten.com/408/287" alt=""></a>
    <a href="01.jpg"><img class="image" src="https://placekitten.com/408/287" alt=""></a>
  </div>
</main>
```

Hopefully this helps you work out how to get the spacing you're after. If you can't figure it out on your own from here, edit your question and include a quick sketch of how you want your layout to look and I'll update my answer.

Comment: I've added some height:100vh; to the main, that was the problem :) Thank you!

Comment: Just be cautious of viewport changes on mobile devices